# How to display directories that begins with small or capital letter in Linux?

Tags: linux, grep, directory, ls, text-search

I want to display all directory names in directory `/opt/BMC/patrol/` that begin with `Patrol*` or `patrol*`. Command

```
ls /opt/BMC/patrol/ | grep -i '^Patrol*'
```

produces

```
Patrol3
Patrol3.16
PatrolAgent_3181.sh
patrol_cfg.sh
```

It is correct but there are directories and files, instead of just directories.

Command `ls -d /opt/BMC/patrol/*/ | grep -i '^Patrol*'` produces nothing...

Command `ls -d /opt/BMC/patrol/*/ | grep -i 'Patrol*'` produces

```
/opt/BMC/patrol/BMCINSTALL/
/opt/BMC/patrol/bmc_products/
/opt/BMC/patrol/cert_gg/
/opt/BMC/patrol/common/
/opt/BMC/patrol/Install/
/opt/BMC/patrol/itools/
/opt/BMC/patrol/Patrol3/
/opt/BMC/patrol/Patrol3.16/
/opt/BMC/patrol/perform/
/opt/BMC/patrol/rtserver/
/opt/BMC/patrol/temp2/
/opt/BMC/patrol/test/
/opt/BMC/patrol/testftp/
/opt/BMC/patrol/Uninstall/
```

Does it search recursively?  What is a command to find only directory names that begins with capital or small letters?

Comment: By the way, a belated welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about how the site runs.

Answer (score 2):

Try `find`:

```
find /opt/BMC/patrol -type d -iname 'patrol*'
```

`-type d` matches directories, and `-iname` is a case-insensitive match.  The `'patrol*'` has to be quoted `''` because otherwise the shell will expand the `*` before `find` gets a chance.

`find` does search recursively by default (see Edit 2, below).

**Edit** `ls` is not optimized for this use case.  `ls -d` prevents descending into directories, which is why you don't get any matches.  As far as `grep` goes, `^` matches at the beginning of the line, not at the leading `/` before a directory's name.  So `grep -i '\/patrol'` would be a way to find names beginning with `Patrol` or `patrol`, but you would still have to filter down to directories.  `find` is designed to handle all these things.

**Edit 2** For non-recursive, use `-maxdepth`:

```
find /opt/BMC/patrol -maxdepth 1 -type d -iname 'patrol*'
```

I made a test directory with the following contents, based on your question:

```
opt/BMC/patrol/
opt/BMC/patrol/BMCINSTALL/
opt/BMC/patrol/bmc_products/
opt/BMC/patrol/cert_gg/
opt/BMC/patrol/common/
opt/BMC/patrol/common/patrol.d/
opt/BMC/patrol/Install/
opt/BMC/patrol/itools/
opt/BMC/patrol/Patrol3/
opt/BMC/patrol/Patrol3.16/
opt/BMC/patrol/PatrolAgent_3181.sh
opt/BMC/patrol/patrol_cfg.sh
opt/BMC/patrol/perform/
opt/BMC/patrol/rtserver/
opt/BMC/patrol/temp2/
opt/BMC/patrol/test/
opt/BMC/patrol/testftp/
opt/BMC/patrol/Uninstall/
```

When I run the first command (without `-maxdepth`), I get:

```
opt/BMC/patrol
opt/BMC/patrol/common/patrol.d
opt/BMC/patrol/Patrol3
opt/BMC/patrol/Patrol3.16
```

When I run the second command (with `-maxdepth`), I get:

```
opt/BMC/patrol
opt/BMC/patrol/Patrol3
opt/BMC/patrol/Patrol3.16
```

and `common/patrol.d` is not present in the results.

Comment: It works but again it searches recursively and also in subdirectories beacuse I get 
`/opt/BMC/patrol/

/opt/BMC/patrol/Patrol3

/opt/BMC/patrol/common/patrol.d

/opt/BMC/patrol/Patrol3.16`

Comment: @ag.lis Do you want non-recursive?  If so, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46790208/edit) to clarify.  Thanks!